# How do I add a local mirror to my software sources?

Tags: 10.10, repository

My institute hosts ubuntu repositories and I have added them.

However, whenever I am downloading any software from synaptic/software_centre, it downloads from the main ubuntu server and not my institute's server. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Replace the 'main server' (is there such a thing?) by the repositories from your institute.

Comment: The drop down menu (which is 'main server' by default) does not have the option of my institute.

Comment: Hm..., then you'll have to edit the repositories file manually and replace the main ones by whatever the institute provides. The file in question is `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "software sources" > Ubuntu Software > Download From > Choose Server> look for your "institute hosts" > select and save. Let it update.

Open a terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type`sudo apt-get update`

### Done

[image]

Comment: My institutes name is not in this list.

Comment: what is it? put the link here

Comment: The link - `mirror.cse.iitd.ac.in`. Well my problem was solved using `mikewhatever`'s comment.